# Split a column into 2 columns mysql table

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have this column in mysql table:

```
LOT_LOCATION
SGBAKE.0013
SGHAST.0008Z1
SGHAST.0011ZU
```

How to split to this table[MANAGED TO DO SO BUT DK HOW TO CHANGE THE TABLE ITSELF):

```
LOT_LOCATION, Zone Attribute
SGBAKE.0013, ''
SGHAST.0008, Z1
SGHAST.0011, ZU
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

my code only select 2 columns but does not alter the table and I dont know how to put condition in creation and alteration of columns:

```
select if(locate('Z',LOT_LOCATION)=0,LOT_LOCATION,substring_index(LOT_LOCATION, 'Z', 1)), 
       if(locate('Z',LOT_LOCATION)=0,'',substring_index(LOT_LOCATION, 'Z', -1)) 
            As Zone_Attribute 
from skynet_msa.Lab_WIP_History;
```

I tried this UPDATE but suddenly the zone attribute column values disappear

```
UPDATE Lab_WIP_History
    SET LOT_LOCATION = if(locate('Z',LOT_LOCATION)=0,LOT_LOCATION,substring_index(LOT_LOCATION, 'Z', 1)), 
    `Zone Attribute` = if(locate('Z',LOT_LOCATION)=0,'',substring_index(LOT_LOCATION, 'Z', -1))
```

Comment: Are there always going to be 6 letters, a dot, 4 numbers and then maybe the 2 characters you want?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem are you having using the available string functions?

Comment: A very good place to start on these requirements is the MySQL Documentation, there is a section in there called [String Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i edited the qn and u can see

Comment: Have you created the new column ?

Comment: yes i have created

Comment: So now you convert the SELECT query to an UPDATE query

Comment: I tried this but it gives me syntax error on the first if : UPDATE if(locate('Z',LOT_LOCATION)=0,LOT_LOCATION,substring_index(LOT_LOCATION, 'Z', 1)) As LOT_LOCATION, 
       if(locate('Z',LOT_LOCATION)=0,'',substring_index(LOT_LOCATION, 'Z', -1)) 
            As Zone_Attribute 
from skynet_msa.Lab_WIP_History;

Comment: Thats because that is not the syntax for an UPDATE query. Can I introduce you to a useful little site that is designed to help people [learn SQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245546/discussion-between-gracella-q-sumarlin-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: lot_location is updated before zone_attribute - ie the zone_attribute test  finds no z in lot_location btw your select query does not produce the result you claim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lot_location is updated before zone_attribute - ie the zone_attribute test finds no z in lot_location btw your select query does not produce the result you claim

reverse the order of the set statement

```
UPDATE Lab_WIP_History
    SET `Zone Attribute` = if(locate('Z',LOT_LOCATION)=0,'',substring_index(LOT_LOCATION, 'Z', -1)), 
     LOT_LOCATION = if(locate('Z',LOT_LOCATION)=0,LOT_LOCATION,substring_index(LOT_LOCATION, 'Z', 1))
;
```